# Google App Script: URL in template literal results in "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"

Tags: google-apps-script

If I have this `onOpen()` setup for a Google Docs Add On:

```
function onOpen(e) {
    DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
        .addItem('Edit Template', 'showSidebar')
        .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
    const html = HtmlService
        .createHtmlOutputFromFile("dist/addOn");
    html.setTitle("DocsNData Template Editor");
    DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```

and if `dist/addOn.html` contains this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        let x = `https://api.airtable.com`;
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

I get this error in the browser console when I try to launch the Add On:

`userCodeAppPanel:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

If I change the contents of the string so it's not a url, it works.  This works in other words:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        let x = `abc`;
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

So it's not the use of a template literal that is the problem.

In addition, referencing a URL as a normal string works, i.e. this is fine:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        let x = "https://api.airtable.com";
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

So URLs in strings are not a problem, template literals are not a problem, its urls in template literals that are the problem.  I have two questions:

1. Why is this the case and whats the right corrective action?
2. How do the line numbers reported in the error messages relate to my source?

Comment: Although I searched this at Google Issue Tracker, I couldn't find it. So I reported this to Google Issue Tracker. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156139610 I hope for being resolved.

Comment: @Tanaike The issue link will be better reached if put in your answer or this question

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your comment. I added it in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Q1: Why is this the case and whats the right corrective action?
- Q2: How do the line numbers reported in the error messages relate to my source?

For these questions, how about this answer?

### A1:

I have experienced the same situation. In this case, I used the following workaround.

#### From:

```
let x = `https://api.airtable.com`;
```

#### To:

```
let x = `https:\/\/api.airtable.com`;
```

- When `` let x = `https://api.airtable.com`; `` is used at Google Apps Script side, no error occurs. So I think that this might be the current specification or a bug.
- **Google Issue Tracker**: Although I searched this issue at Google Issue Tracker, I couldn't find it. So I reported this to Google Issue Tracker. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156139610

### A2:

About `userCodeAppPanel:3`, I think that at first, it is required to confirm the error message. When the error message of `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` is seen, this means the incomplete syntax. By this, it is considered that the error occurs at the end of script of `<script>...</script>`. In this case, `3` is the same with the length of the lines in `<script>...</script>`.

When your following script is seen, the error occurs at `` let x = `https://api.airtable.com`; ``. But the error line is the end of script of `<script>...</script>`. By this, `3` is returned.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        let x = `https://api.airtable.com`;
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

In the case of following sample script, `userCodeAppPanel:5 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` is returned. Because the line of `</script>` is at 5th line.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        let x = `https://api.airtable.com`;


    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

As an another sample, when the following script is seen,

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    let x = "https://api.airtable.com";

    console.log(y);
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

An error occurs like `Uncaught ReferenceError: y is not defined at userCodeAppPanel:4`. In this case, the error line can be clearly found. So `4` is the line of `console.log(y);`.

Unfortunately, I have not been able to be found about this at the official document.

Comment: Thanks! This saved me a lot of headaches. I was like what is going on here!